# Does any xml-based standard exist to define HTTP requests and responses as xml files?

Tags: xml, http, metadata, standards

I am thinking on an XML format, which describes an actual http request (or response). Intuitively, I am thinking on some similar:

```
<response>
  <status>200</status>
  <headers>
    <header><name>Content-Type</name><value>text/html</value></header>
    <header><name>Cache-control</name><value>no-cache</value></header>
  </headers>
  <body><!---CDATA<html><head...title and so on...</html>--></body>
</response>
```

Does this, or any similar exist? I think, it might be very useful for metadata processing using both standardized and effective solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see here:

http://expath.org/modules/http-client/

This module defines a set of functions to send HTTP & HTTPS requests and handle responses. This is a quite low-level functionality, allowing one to deal with most aspects of the HTTP protocol (redirections, headers, body contents, multipart...), while integrating smoothly within the [XPath Data Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/).